# Lucene performance

Tags: java, performance, lucene

could you please suggest on the steps to be followed for lucene performance. especially with large data (around 1TB of pdf files to be indexed)

Answer (score 9):

1. Read [Scaling Lucene and Solr](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Scaling-Lucene-and-Solr).
2. Define your needs from Lucene (for example: you are indexing PDFs - do you need to store the full text, just to make it searchable, or not at all?)
3. Make a small-scale experiment - index a few documents, see whether retrieval is good enough.
4. Try to index the whole thing (considering the paper's tips for quick indexing and for indexing for retrieval speed) - Is retrieval good enough? Is performance good enough?
5. Iterate.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. how difficult to convert lucene implementation to solr implementation?

Comment: I never tried. From what I am hearing, it is very easy to start using Solr. Maybe you should try Solr on a small scale. Maybe I should take my own advice...

Answer (score 6):

Please check the tips on the question [Optimizing Lucene Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668441/optimizing-lucene-performance/668875). Since you are working with large amount of data, you also need to watch the index creation performance. Some tips on [improving indexing performance](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed) and [search performance](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed) are available on Lucene Wiki.